# Tensorflow - What does Training and Prediction mode mean when making a model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network

So, I've googled prior to asking this, obviously, however, there doesn't seem to be much mention on these modes directly. Tensorflow documentation mentions "test" mode in passing which, upon further reading, didn't make very much sense to me.

From what I've gathered, my best shot at this is that to reduce ram, when your model is in prediction mode, you just use a pretrained model to make some predictions based on your input?

If someone could help with this and help me understand, I would be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Training refers to the part where your neural network learns. By learning I mean how your model changes it's weights to improve it's performance on a task given a dataset. This is achieved using the backpropogation algorithm.

Predicting, on the other hand, does not involve any learning. It is only to see how well your model performs after it has been trained. There are no changes made to the model when it is in prediction mode.

Comment: Thank you - this helped a lot.  So would it be correct to say that when your model is in prediction mode, you are just feeding new input onto a pretrained model? Or is it just loading the .h5 file and then use the model for predictions?

Comment: They can both mean the same things. If you have saved your trained model, you can load it later and use it for prediction or do prediction right after you've trained it in which case you don't have to load any files as the model is already in memory.